# How to find Source for HTML Email

Tags: email, html

How to find the source of  HTML Email on Outlook or Thunderbird ? is there any plug-in for that ?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/ to get into superuser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For each of the following, open the message then:

- **Outlook 2003**: Right-click anywhere in the message and select *View Source*
- **Outlook 2007**: Select *Other Actions* > *View Source*
- **Thunderbird**: Select *View* > *Message Source* (or hit Ctrl+U)

Comment: I think these will all show the the source of the entire raw message, including headers and potentially multiple message parts. The html is just one part, and when it's included in the message it's generally encoded using either quoted-printable or base64 encoding. It needs to be decoded to be viewed as HTML.

Comment: Note that Outlook does not really show the raw source, but only the displayed textual part, and it's not raw but decoded from quoted-printable or base64. All other mail clients I know do display the raw source (= how the message has actually been transferred).

Answer (score 4):

In outlook 2007, open mail message and click other actions -> View source

Comment: At least Outlook Express/Windows Mail used the shortcut Alt+F3, I think. It's been a while that I used that, though. But this may work in Outlook too.

Answer (score 4):

In Thunderbird it's *View -> Message Source*, which is bound to control-U.

Answer (score 4):

In Thunderbird, type CTRL + U when the mail message has focus.

Or in the Menu > View > Message Source.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful: sometimes sending things through Outlook distorts the source.  E.G. if you have a pure HTML email sent, and view source in outlook, it can add all type of garbage to it if what you're after is the pure HTML.

Comment: Also, email addresses may be changed into what has been set up on the server... Like if I send a message to "Boss <steve@example.org>" then Exchange or Outlook will change that into "Steve Ballmer <steve@example.org>". Likewise, if messages are forwarded, then you might only see the final recipient, not the recipient to which the message was actually sent! (WHY...?) There are some registry hacks to avoid some of those conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Because the menu ribbon sucks to navigate:

- **Outlook 2010**: Actions > Other Actions > View Source

[image: Outlook 2010 - View Source]